# Vacuum Fluorescent Display (VFD) + Teensy 4.1 (wiring check)

Tags: teensy, vacuum-fluorescent

In my current project I would like to control a Vacuum Fluorescent Display (VFD) with my Teensy 4.1.
I have made a wiring plan but since I don't have much experience in electronics I would appreciate your feedback.

**Main question:** Would this setup work? *(see image attached)*

- Power supply: 5V 2A Adapter
- Filament power: step down module 5V to 2.5-3V
- Grid/segment power: step up module 5V to 12-30V
- Logic level converter 3.3 to 5V: SN74AHCT125N
- VFD driver: HV5812P

**Bonus question:**

- Driving the filament with AC instead of DC would be much better, but I'm not sure what the easiest way would be to accomplish that. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

[image: Teensy VFD wiring plan]

Comment: If this is a one off, for the filament just use an H-Bridge chip and drive it with a square wave AC.  Also, just using DC will be fine for months before a gradient is observed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will take a look at your H-Bridge chip suggestion, but it is good to know that DS will probably work fine.